# Unpredictable behavior after compiling

Tags: autoit

so I have script in autoIT and it works fine, but after compiling in to the exe has different behavior like script.

```
Run("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe")
WinWaitActive("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe")
send("ImporatntExecutable /regserver" & "{ENTER}")
send("regsvr32 Important.dll" & "{Enter}")
```

So, script perfectly performs this commands, but exe compiled from script no. Command line in exe case seems like:

```
rImportant.dll
```

**or**

```
reImportant.dll
```

Such commands don't exist, so I get errors, but string in command is *regsvr32 Important.dll* and no *rImportant.dll* or *reImportant.dll*. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you send keys to cmd window? Why not just execute those commands from the script? You might be the first one who has ever tried this.

Comment: Because this sequence must be automated and batch file(executable required) is unacceptable. Also if your name not lied to me, greetings my Czech brother ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your script this way:

```
Run("ImporatntExecutable /regserver")
Run("regsvr32 Important.dll")
```

and you can compile it to exe. No need to send keystrokes to cmd window.

If you still need to send keystrokes to cmd window for whatever (for me incomprehensible) reason you can try [add this line](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/AutoItSetOption.htm#SendKeyDelay) at the beginning your script:

```
Opt ("SendKeyDelay", 500)
```

Perhaps the compiled script is too fast for cmd window.

Comment: Without keystroke command isn't executing. So I have command typed in commandline and next to him is another command. But with key delay is string in command window correct and that was my primary problem,  thank you :)